# Глагол "спать" относится к 1-му спряжению?

Tags: глаголы, спряжение, морфология

Согласно книге Розенталя, ко 2-му спряжению относятся 4 глагола на -ать: *гнать*, *держать*, *дышать*, *слышать*. Глагола *спать* в списке нет, следовательно у него должно быть окончание 1-го спряжения: *ты сп**е**шь*. Но на самом деле *ты сп**и**шь*. Почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Глагол "спать" относится к глаголам второго спряжения, на это указывает его окончание - ИТ. По инфинитиву определяется спряжение только глаголов с безударным личным окончанием.

Comment: Что значит "определяется по инфинитиву"? Как вы определите спряжение по инфинитиву, например, [глад'ьт'] - какая там должна быть буква перед "ть"?

Спряжение - просто условная схема, связывающая написание разных форм глагола. Действует эта схема да, только для безударных окончаний (и то не всегда, как справедливо заметила @Vera).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь интересен пример глагола "выспишься". Приставка ВЫ перетягивает на себя ударение: спать - выспаться, и по правилу он должен относиться к 1-му спряжению  Однако для подобных глаголов спряжение определяется без приставки ВЫ.

Также: шить - шьешь, вышить - вышьешь (глагол 1-го спряжения).

Comment: А также "вылить - лить - льешь - выльешь", " вылететь - лететь - летит - вылетит"